# Xamarin forms ios app rejected due to Deprecated API Usage UIWebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin.forms app which have a webview. Whenever I try to publish the app to apple app store I get the `Deprecated API Usage UIWebView` warning and my app gets rejected. I saw the issue raised in https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323. But I could't fix my issue. I replaced the webView using this render.

```
  public class MyWebView : WebView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Url",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Url
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

**On ios part**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace WKWebViewDemo.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also added  **--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type** as additional mtouch arguments and published the app. Still got rejected. How to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

My xamarin.forms verion `:4.6.0.847`

xamarin.ios version : `13.16.0.13`

Comment: A custom renderer is not necessary to fix this.  What is your linker set to?  Are you using any third party libraries or nuget packages that might be referencing UIWebView?

Comment: My linker settings is Link Sdk only

Comment: also, if you are updating an existing app Apple will just warn you, you can still publish until December 2020.

Comment: No, Iam not updating, I am publishing a new app. It is removing from appstoreconnect

Comment: My other packages are FFImageLoading,Pancakeview,Newtonsoft,Xamarin.forms lottie, Xamarin.essentials

Comment: @Jason SIr, How to solve this?

Comment: try link all , also check grep on the ipa file to see whats causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't post this as a comment, because I wanted to share a picture.

This happened to me before too, where I set `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type` but I still got that error.

My issue was that I set those additional mtouch arguments for the wrong configuration. As you can see in the image, make sure you are placing those values in the right configuration and platform! It should be the same combination that you use for creating the archive:
 [image: Visual Studio screenshot showing the iOS Project options]

Comment: Thanks bro. It was the issue. It was set for simulator.How silly I am

Comment: :) Happens to the best of us. I couldnt believe i had wasted our of my time creating an archive and publishing it, only to get that error